# Convert "Who has stolen my spectacles?" to passive voice

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Convert this sentence to passive voice:
Who has stolen my spectacles?
I got two options: a)by whom spectacles have been stolen? B)by whom have my spectacles been stolen? I am confused regarding position of 'have'.Pls clarify this.

Comment: By whom were my spectacles stolen?

Comment: Or *My spectacles have been stolen by whom*?

Comment: I'm certain this question has been asked before, but I cannot be asked to search through the archives, so I am voting to close this question for lack of research. EL&U shouldn't be doing your homework, so you're very lucky that you got any answers at all. Tsk! *wags her finger at naughty pupil*

Answer (score 2):

The most natural option is:

> Who were my spectacles stolen by?

Or two rather more formal options:

> Whom were my spectacles stolen by?
>
> By whom were my spectacles stolen?

Generally, it is helpful to turn the original question around to a statement, *Tom stole my spectacles!* then change the statement to passive, *My spectacles were stolen by Tom!* and then turn it back to a question.

There’s an extra twist here, because *by Tom* turns into *by who?* when you make it a question, and then *who* occurs as the object of a preposition, things get a bit subtle.  The more traditional rule, still followed in much formal writing, is that *who* should change to *whom*, and the preposition can either stay with it at the start of the question or move to the end.  The standard modern usage in speech and much writing, though, is to just use *who*, and always put the preposition to the end.

---

Worth noting that I also made a small change in tense/aspect: *My spectacles were stolen by Tom* strictly corresponds to *Tom stole my spectacles*, while *Tom has stolen my spectacles* would become *My spectacles have been stolen by Tom.*  So to stay absolutely parallel with the original sentence, the question could be *Who have my spectacles been stolen by?*  (or *Whom…* or *By whom…*).  This sounds quite awkward to me, though — not ungrammatical, but noticeably less natural than *Who were my spectacles stolen by*; and the change in aspect doesn’t affect the meaning much in this case.

Comment: I think very careful speakers would find "Whom were my spectacles stolen by?" to be jarring (I.e "The don't finish the sentence with a preposition" brigade.) I find the "By whom were ...." to be VERY formal, not at all close to being "slightly"

Comment: @Mari-LouA: yes, I agree that the difference in formality is bigger than my current wording suggests; will edit that.  As for the “don’t finish the sentence with a proposition” brigade, though, I don’t see any good reason to defer to them.  “It must be whom not who!” has genuinely been a rule of grammar, even if it’s largely archaic now; but “Don’t end with a proposition” is an entirely invented shibboleth.  (Or, at best, it’s a completely inaccurate statement of the actual rules governing preposition-stranding.)

Comment: Yes, but if "whom" is considered to be the only correct pronoun by those speakers they're unlikely to commit the "sin" of ending a sentence with a preposition.

Comment: I general I agree that not ending sentences with a preposition is a nonsense rule, but to my ear it sounds pretty strange to use the preposition ending in concert with "whom."  I'd go with "who... by" or "by whom."